# How can a custom control get the handle of an other control?

Tags: c#, custom-controls

I have a main form (mainForm1) with a TextBox (textBox1) and a custom control (constomControl1).

The custom control needs the value in textBox1.

I see a few approaches:

- The custom control could drill up the parents until it finds the main form, then ask for mainForm1.textBox1.Text
- When the custom control is created, the main form can pass it its own handle through the constructor: MyCustomControl myCustomControl = new MyCustomControl(this), which the custom control can store in a private variable (mainForm1); then the custom control can use it to get to the TextBox: mainForm1.textBox1.Text
- The main form can store its handle in a global variable, which the custom control can access, and then ask for mainForm1.textBox1.Text

Are any of these approaches appropriate?

Comment: I would recommend not going directly from the custom control to the textbox--which defeats the purpose of a custom control by coupling to something on a specific form.  If you need the value, I'd suggest hooking up to the update events on the textbox and informing the custom control of the changes.

Comment: Don't do any of those, none of them are appropriate. Just expose a property on the custom control and have the form update it with the necessary value.

Comment: > Just expose a property on the custom control and have the form update it with the necessary value   -- The form would have to scan all its controls, to make a list of every instance of MyCustomControl, and then tell each of them the value in mainForm1.textBox1.Text. Not only does that sound like a lot of extra work for the form to do; it also makes N+1 copies of that value (where N is the number of instances of MyCustomControl), and I have learned that having more than 1 copy of a value is asking for trouble (in case not all copies are synchronized).